# I've been told that I can calculate how high some one is jumping on a trampoline by timing 10 bounces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, spring, estimation

I am attending a school (in Oakland CA), taking trampoline classes, none of the trainers are aware of the equation used for determining height jumped. I would guess this is a simple question for this exchange but I am hoping someone is willing to help out.

Comment: Neglecting the contact time with the trampoline, it would be $H=\frac{1}{2}g(T/20)^2$. The correction due to the fact that the trampoline is not infinitely stiff will make the calculated height lower--the softer the trampoline, the bigger the correction.

Comment: Yeah, the basic point is that one must have a certain velocity when leaving the trampoline surface in order to achieve a given height, and that would be the same velocity achieved at the end of the downward fall from that height -- just like the timing of throwing a ball straight up into the air.  (I'll assume Ben's equation is correct, since it would take me an hour to derive it, and even then my confidence level would be low.)

Comment: (Do note that, as Ben suggests, the calculations are hosed up a bit by the time the gymnast spends actually in contact with the trampoline surface -- this time is harder to account for, and hence the equation is less accurate for short bounces.)

Comment: looking at the math and it turns out the amount of time spent bouncing on a (round)  trampoline does not depend on the height, speed or deflection. It does come out that the bounce speed $v \propto \delta^2$, where $\delta$ is the deflection of the trampoline.

Comment: @ja72 - But the time spent in the air *does* depend on height/speed, and in most cases the time in the air is significantly greater than the time in contact with the surface.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12976/392

Comment: Also related: https://packerphysics9.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/collect-data-and-analyze-motion/

Answer (score 4):

In very simplistic terms the total time per jump cycle is broken down to two parts.

- Time spent in the air decelerating downwards by $g$
- Time spent in contact with the trampoline accelerating upwards by $a$

The total time $T$ is

$$ T = \frac{2 v}{a} + \frac{2 v}{g} $$

where $v$ is the launch velocity (equalling the impact velocity). The total jump height can be estimated from the launch velocity $$ h = \frac{v^2}{2 g}$$

Combined the above give us an estimate of the height based on time *only* if the acceleration $a$ is known, as well as the total time $T$ and gravity $g$.

$$ h = \frac{T^2 a^2 g}{8 (a+g)^2} $$

In [this post](https://packerphysics9.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/collect-data-and-analyze-motion/) the acceleration is measured from video data for a particular kind of trampoline.

Using this data of $a=26.6\;\mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}}$, $g=9.81\;\mathrm{ \frac{m}{s^2}}$ you get

$$ h\mbox{ [meters]} = 0.621 (T \mbox{ [seconds]})^2 $$

[image: pic]

As an example, if the total time is $T=1.95\,{\rm s}$ then the height should be $$ h = 0.621\cdot (1.95)^2 = 2.36\,{\rm m} $$

Comment: It would also be possible to calibrate the equation  with a known height. In that case, you simply need only take the proportion:  $h/h_0 = (T/T_0)^2$.

Comment: Well I have to say that I am impressed, to get any response at all and the speed of the response so first of all thank you.

Comment: Well, I have to say that I am impressed, to get any response at all and Iam impressed with the speed of the response. Thank you. This is all very much over my head. What would be really helpful is if I can give you a sample time that could be used to solve the problem. Then I could see how it works. I realize it might not be 100% accurate but if used on the same trampoline at the school, all jumps would be relative to each other. The time I would propose to use is 19.47 seconds.

Comment: You would need to measure or estimate the acceleration rate when jumping in order to get to an absolute height. Otherwise, you can only compare as @cms stated in the comments between two heights and two times $$ \frac{h_1}{h_2} = \left( \frac{T_1}{T_2} \right)^2 $$

Comment: $T=19.47$ is probably incorrect. 2o seconds means you reach 200+ meters high.

Comment: @ja72 OP refers to timing 10 jumps, so presumably 19.47 seconds refers to 1.947 seconds per jump.

Comment: @Chris - Yeah, that's how I interpreted also in my example above.

Answer (score 0):

While you can do this by timing *n* bounces, it's tricky to separate the time of the rebound separate from the air time.

I ran into an article online that considered the rebound part to be a simple harmonic oscillator.  Some tests showed that while the time to do 60 bounces at just barely perceptable movement up to the point where feet were about to leave the mat it was indeed, a very uniform time.  (within a second) when I used this time as bounce time later I got absurd results.

The return force on a trampoline is messy.

- As the displacement increases are resistance becomes a significant factor.
- When the mat is close to level, the tension on the mat nearly cancels out, as the mat is deformed, the vector cancellation decreases.  Force increases as the sin of the angle of the cone of depression.  So far, all in accord with SHM.  But also you are stretching the springs, so there is a multiplier.  I *think* for first order approximation, that the force goes up as the square of the angle of depression.

However, there is an easier way.

Video it with your phone on a slo-mo setting.  Now time some number of jumps, while videoing it. I suggest using at least 30 to minimize start/stop timing errors.

Analyze the vid counting frames for several sample bounces, and the subsequent air time.

Example:  YOur 60 jump time is 80 seconds.  Counting frames, the bounce takes 16 and the jump 24.  Use ratio and proportion, this means you spent 48 secons in the air and 32 on the mat.

48 seconds is 0.8 seconds per jump.  Thats Up and Down time, so use half that time 0.4 seconds for the falling time.  $$d = {1\over2} at^2$$

$$d= {1\over2} * 10 * 0.4^2$$

$$d = 0.8 m$$